# Adobe Captivate & SCORM: Navigate to next SCO

Tags: scorm, scorm2004, adobe-captivate

I am attempting to navigate to the next SCO using the call "adl.nav.request" in SCORM 2004. However, I am relatively new to creating SCORM content using Captivate and what I am trying doesn't seem to be working. The code I am using is:

```
// NOT WORKING IN DEFAULT CAPTIVATE TEMPLATE HTML/JS FILES
CaptivateObj.SetScormVariable("adl.nav.request","{target=sco2_item}choice");
CaptivateObj.SetScormVariable("terminate", "");
```

To verify that it's an issue with this particular code, I bypassed the default Captivate HTML/JS files and used my own along with a custom SCORM Wrapper in which I was able to connect to the SCORM API and successfully navigate to the next SCO using the parameters below:

```
// WORKING IN CUSTOM SCORM WRAPPER
 setScormVariable("adl.nav.request","{target=sco2_item}choice");
 setScormVariable("terminate","");
```

With that said, I assume the initial Captivate code is not correct. Can someone point me in the correct direction?

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
SCORM2004_CallSetValue("adl.nav.request","{target=sco2_item}choice");
SCORM2004_CallTerminate();
```